# Create a trigger to insert records from a table to another one. Get inserted values in a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `tbl_PurchaseDetails` and `tbl_ItemDetails`. I need to insert some rows into `tbl_ItemDetails` from `tbl_PurchaseDetails`, right after it is inserted in `tbl_PurchaseDetails`. I know the problem but i am unable to solve it. Please help.

I have written the following code for the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_UpdateItemDetails ON tbl_PurchaseDetails
FOR INSERT AS
DECLARE @PurchaseID VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Quantity INT
DECLARE @WarehouseID VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @PurchaseID=(PurchaseID) FROM INSERTED
SELECT @Quantity=(ItemQuantity) FROM INSERTED
SELECT @WarehouseID=(WarehouseID) FROM INSERTED

INSERT INTO 
tbl_ItemDetails
(PurchaseID,Quantity,WarehouseID)
VALUES
(
@PurchaseID,@Quantity,@WarehouseID
)
```

And now when I insert into `tbl_PurchaseDetails` the rows are added to `tbl_PurchaseDetails` but not to `tbl_ItemDetails`. It throws the following error:

> *Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure trigger_UpdateItemDetails, Line 11
>
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PurchaseID', table 'dbStockHandling.dbo.tbl_ItemDetails'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.*

My question is how to get the inserted values from `tbl_PurchaseDetails` so that the trigger can insert them into `tbl_ItemDetails`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_UpdateItemDetails ON tbl_PurchaseDetails
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO 
    tbl_ItemDetails
    (
        PurchaseID,
        Quantity,
        WarehouseID
    )
    SELECT 
        PurchaseID, 
        ItemQuantity, 
        WarehouseID
    FROM 
        INSERTED
END
```

and make sure that you are inserting a `NOT NULL` value to column `PurchaseID` of table `tbl_PurchaseDetails`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Actually both the triggers work fine. I wanted a auto increment field in 'tbl_ItemDetails', which i didn't implement, which is why the error occurred. Thank you again. :D