# SQL Trigger on insert, only for new rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I would like to run a query when the data in table is inserted. So when a data is inserted in table 1, trigger is executed and it runs a query **only on new inserted data**, and inserts results of this query into table 2.

I already have a trigger, but query executed in trigger applies for all records in table, i only want it to apply it to new inserted records.

My code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig
ON Table1
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table2
        SELECT
            --my query code is here
        FROM 
            Table1
        GROUP BY
            TransportID
END
GO
```

Comment: Use the `inserted` object. You can find examples in the documentation [Create DML Triggers - SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-dml-triggers?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: changed to: From inserted. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this gives you output as per your expectation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig ON table1 after 
INSERT AS BEGIN 
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT 
         --your query code is here 
from     INSERTED -- JUST ADD THIS --
GROUP BY transportid 
END
GO
```

I have solution from given reference :https://stackoverflow.com/a/15239826/6923146